# Oxford Entrance Exam MAT 1998: Solution verifcaition

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, combinations

I need confirmation for the solution for part (d) of the following question from the 1998 MAT Oxford Exam:

[image]

My formula is $W_n= 2 r_{n-3} +r_{n-2}$. Is this correct for part (d)? If not please just say no as I want to go over my work and try to figure it out for myself.

Comment: had an latex error that I just fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems right

enumerate   $BW[\cdots]W, \;\; W[\cdots]WB, \;\; W[\cdots]W$